# how to replace existing fragment in a fragment manager with another fragment based on tag

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

i have an activity that will show data using fragment, for each fragment i give the unique id as the Tag like this:

```
public class MyActivity .... {

    void addFragment(String id){
        // this is how i add a new fragment
        FragmentTransaction fTrans = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

        AnyFragment frag = new AnyFragment();

        fTrans.add(R.id.container, frag, id);
        fTrans.commit();
    }

    void replaceFragment(String id){
        // this is how i replace the fragment with tag 'id' with new fragment
        FragmentTransaction fTrans = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

        AnyFragment newFrag = new AnyFragment();
        fTrans.replace(R.id.container, newFrag, id);
        fTrans.commit();
    }

}
```

In my **example** i have add 2 fragment with tag '**data1**' and '**data2**'.

When i'm tried to replace the fragment with tag '**data1**' or '**data2**', it always replacing the fragment which added **first** and when i'm replace for the second time, it replace the **second** added fragment.

When i'm replacing for 3 times, it leave me only one fragment and one other fragment is gone.

**My problem is:**

I want to replace the fragment with specified tag with a new fragment, how to do that? There's something wrong for replace in my code?

Can i use replace method? or i must use remove the fragment with specified tag first then add the new fragment with same tag? What's the best approach to do that? It would be great if you can give some explanation, for each approach.

Any answer would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: I think replace means that replace the fragment that is showing.

Comment: i still didnt know how that replace works, but when i'm remove the old fragment then add the new fragment it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't really need tags in your case:

Check the [method description](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentTransaction.html#replace(int,%20android.support.v4.app.Fragment,%20java.lang.String)) on Android Developer:

> Replace an existing fragment that was added to a container. This is essentially the same as calling remove(Fragment) for all currently added fragments that were added with the same containerViewId and then add(int, Fragment, String) with the same arguments given here.

So all you do is:

1. During `onCreate()` of Activity (or whenever you actually need to instantiate a fragment) - fill the container with a new fragment:
   `getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, Fragment.instantiate(this, FragmentA.class.getName())).commit();`
2. Once you need to replace FragmentA with FragmentB, you just call
   `getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, Fragment.instantiate(this, FragmentB.class.getName())).commit();` (i.e. to tags required - R.id.container has only one fragment at the same time)

If you don't want to `replace` fragments (which is *preferred* solution), you can in `onCreate()` of your activity [`add()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentTransaction.html#add(int,%20android.support.v4.app.Fragment)) both fragments, and then use [`show()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentTransaction.html#show(android.support.v4.app.Fragment)) and [`hide()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentTransaction.html#hide(android.support.v4.app.Fragment)) methods respectively:

```
    Fragment fragmentA = Fragment.instantiate(this, FragmentA.class.getName());
    Fragment fragmentB = Fragment.instantiate(this, FragmentA.class.getName());
    ..
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.container, fragmentA)
            .add(R.id.container, fragmentB)
            .show(fragmentA)
            .hide(fragmentB)
            .commit();

    ..
    // Once you want to show fragment B instead of fragment A
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .show(fragmentB)
            .hide(fragmentA)
            .commit();
```

**UPD:** regarding editing of the existing fragment:

In your Activity, once something happened and you want to update the fragment - do this:

1. In `onCreate()` (or any other suitable place) you add fragment into container(`R.id.container`):
   `getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, Fragment.instantiate(this, FragmentA.class.getName())).commit();`
2. In the place where you want to update - do this:

   ```
   Fragment f = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.container);
   if (f instanceof FragmentA) {
       // doSomething() is a public method of FragmentA;
      ((FragmentA)f).doSomething();
   }
   ```

I hope, it helps

Comment: All i wanna do is to editting the content of the fragment that already added, for example: i have 2 fragment (fragment A and fragment B). I want to edit the content in fragment A, example: i want to setText the TextView inside that fragment. I think that i need to get the Fragment A which already added, edit the content then add it again to the FragmentManager. But if i just add the edited fragment to FragmentManager, it will give me 2 fragments. So i need to replace the old fragment with the fragment that already edited.

But when i'm use replace, it's give me wrong result

Comment: No-no-no, you don't need to re-add fragment after editing! You can do it in place. Just get fragment from fragmentManager (it has such APIs) and edit whatever you need.

Comment: @StanleyGiovany I updated the answer with example of editing existing fragment. Check if it is what you've been looking for.

Comment: great answer! i'm not realize that we can edit the content of fragment without re-add the fragment into fragmentmanager. thanks for your answer, it's help me so much..